# Jquery show only first 5 elements of array

Tags: jquery

I have got this code

```
var Movies = ['Alice in Wonderland', 'Above Suspicion', 'A Christmas Story', 'A Crack in the Floor', 'A Deadly Encounter ', 'A Deadly Vision'];
var results = $.grep(Movies, function(item){
    for(term in results){
        $("#res").append("<li>" + results[term] + "</li>");
    }
```

But it shows all elements and i want it to show only 5 elements of array.How can i do that?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/slice/ is what you are looking for.

Comment: What about that old and boring __for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++}__?

Comment: @Victor i have tried that and that repeats it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**slice()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```
var Movies = ['Alice in Wonderland', 'Above Suspicion', 'A Christmas Story', 'A Crack in the Floor', 'A Deadly Encounter ', 'A Deadly Vision'];
var results = $.grep(Movies.slice(0, 5), function(item){
for(term in results){
    $("#res").append("<li>" + results[term] + "</li>");
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks!That was pretty stupid mistake i didnt know about slice.